# How to find PHP file of a URL in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have access to files and folders of my Wordpress website which is developed by a company and I want to edit the homepage. What I need is how to locate the php file of this page to edit that. 
The page I am trying to find refers to homepage of my website: avang.ir and first of all, I need to know where the referring .PHP file is located by using inspect element of Chrome. 
Besides, I assume a file called page-homepagenew.php is related to this page and this is what I got for the file I assume refers to the URL I need to edit.

```
<?php
/*
 Template Name:homepagenew
*/


//get_template_part('template/main', 'instagram'); 

if(true):

?>

<html xmlns:021-88500805ﺷﻬﺮﺳﺘﺎن="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://avang.ir/wp-content/themes/Avada-child/css/swiper.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://avang.ir/wp-content/themes/Avada-child/css/style-boot.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://avang.ir/wp-content/themes/Avada-child/css/media.css">
</head>



<body>

    <?php get_template_part('template/main', 'header'); ?>

<div class="position-relative">
    <div class="darkness"></div>

    <?php get_template_part('template/main', 'slider'); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('template/main', 'brand'); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('template/main', 'part1'); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('template/main', 'aparat'); ?>
    <?php //get_template_part('template/main', 'instagram'); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('template/main', 'article'); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('template/main', 'product'); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('template/main', 'project'); ?>   
    <?php get_template_part('template/main', 'news'); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('template/main', 'about'); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('template/main', 'footer'); ?>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://avang.ir/wp-content/themes/Avada-child/js/horizontal-accordion.js" type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://avang.ir/wp-content/themes/Avada-child/js/swiper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://avang.ir/wp-content/themes/Avada-child/js/slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://avang.ir/wp-content/themes/Avada-child/js/dimension.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://avang.ir/wp-content/themes/Avada-child/js/crossBrowser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>

<style>




</style>

<script>
   $("#sidebar").hover(function(){
       $(".darkness").css("display","block");
   } , function(){
    $(".darkness").css("display","none");
   });

    $(".navbar-toggler").click(function(){
      var flag =  $(this).attr("aria-expanded");

      if(flag == "false"){   
        $(".darkness").css("display","block");
      }else if(flag == "true"){ 
        $(".darkness").css("display","none");
      }

     })

     $(".darkness").click(function(){
         $("#navbarNavDropdown").removeClass("show");
         $(".darkness").css("display","none");
         $(".navbar-toggler").attr("aria-expanded" , "false");
     })

</script>

</html>
<?php

    endif;
```

Comment: Content is normally stored in the database. This does nothing have to do with programming.

Comment: If its content you should be able to edit that via WordPress backend not php files. IF you need to edit the files but don't know which pages they are related to, sign in to wordpress, go to the page in question and see if it has a template assigned to it

Comment: @Jon Yes Jon. We have two themes installed: a main and a child. The website I am trying to solve the problem for is avang.ir  and the .PHP file is page-homepagenew.php. The problem is the body of the file has nothing in it except some get_template_part referring to some templates I dont know how to find.

Comment: @Arya get_template_part will be referencing another file within the theme, it could be a file inside another folder or a file in the theme root. If you send the full get_template_part code I can advise you where it will be. Or for more reading have a look at: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/